# Comment puis-je commencer un courrier?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, correspondance, salutations

Je suis à la recherche de quelques phrases utiles que je pourrais utiliser pour commencer un échange électronique avec quelqu’un sachant que je le connais déjà. Par exemple :

```
Bonjour,
Je reprends contact avec toi pour partager  
quelques nouvelles...
```

Y a-t-il des moyens plus originaux de démarrer une telle conversation ?

Comment: Il faudrait des informations supplémentaires. Est-ce un ami, de la famille, une connaissance du travail...

Comment: Plutôt une connaissance du travail! Donc ce sera effectivement adressé à quelqu’un avec qui je vais travailler

Answer (score 4):

À titre personnel, j'aime me montrer chaleureux envers mes collègues (dans la mesure du possible) lors des différents échanges. Dans la période actuelle, un petit mot de sympathie montrant que tu te soucies de ton interlocuteur est toujours agréable. Étant donné que tu sembles suffisamment proche de ce collègue pour le tutoyer, je recommande une entrée en matière simple mais efficace :

> Cher [Prénom] / [Prénom] / Bonjour [Prénom],
>
> J'espère que tu vas bien.

ou, pour être plus direct,

> Comment vas-tu ?

Si ce collègue te parle régulièrement de sa famille, tu peux également rendre le tout plus chaleureux avec :

> J'espère que tout le monde va bien.

Et, pour avoir une petite pensée dans le cadre de la pandémie actuelle, terminer le message par :

> Prends soin de toi,

Comment: Oui , merci ! En fait je toujours croyais que la phrase comme « j’espère que vous allez bien » pourrait être un peu banal, car toutes les mails que j’ai reçu normalement commençaient de cette phrase :-)

Comment: C'est effectivement une phrase assez banale, il faut avouer. Si tu connais bien la personne, ça peut être intéressant de rajouter quelque chose de personnel, par exemple `J'espère que tu vas bien et que les examens de ton fils se sont bien passés !` ou `J'espère que tu vas bien et que tu t'en es sorti avec [projet sur lequel il travaillait] !`. Ça permet de montrer que tu l'as écouté quand vous avez discuté par le passé, et que ça t'intéresse réellement de savoir comment il va.

Comment: Merci !mais serait-il possible de dire au début de mail « comment cela se passe de ton côté ? » quelle sera la différence par rapport de « ça va ? »

Comment: Quand tu dis "comment cela se passe" ou "comment ça se passe", tu fais référence à quelque chose de précis (par exemple si le collègue t'a parlé de son déménagement et qu'il est en train de le faire). Ce n'est pas exactement comme le "how is it going" anglais, qui est plus général et se traduirait plutôt par "Comment ça va ?". Un terme plus familier, à n'utiliser que pour un ami, pourrait être `Quoi de neuf ?` (What's up), ou même `Ça roule ?` (encore un peu plus familier).

Comment: D’accord, c’est bien noté ! Merci !